# Keyboard Shortcuts in my JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I was wondering if there is a way to make an easy keyboard shortcut in my JSF page

each page has several buttons and I would like to be able to have a user press something like alt+a to activate a button called 'Add Report to Group'

in .net you just put an & before the letter you want to be the shortcut key, is there an option like this in JSF (apart from writing some javascript code which is what I found on the web)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the HTML-provided `accesskey` attribute which is also mapped in [`<h:commandButton>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html) and [`<h:commandLink>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/commandLink.html).

```
<h:commandButton value="Add" accesskey="a" action="#{bean.add}" />
```

This button can then be invoked by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, depending on the browser used.

Comment: I tried 

'<h:commandButton value="Add Uploaded Reports" accesskey="a" action="#{controls.addTable}"/>'

and I get nothing, one sec I try rebuilding and cleaning and running again

Comment: What browser? What is Shift+Alt+1 supposed to do?

Comment: Firefox 4 I tried a new key(1) like you suggested but when that failed I just tried a bunch of random ctrl, shift alt combos and it worked when I pressed Shift+Alt+1

Comment: Use `Shift+Alt+A`. That extra Shift key in Firefox is also new to me. I'll update the answer. I'd consider to make it `accesskey="A"` instead and use `Shift+Alt+A` all the time so that it also works on other/older browsers. Chrome for example just works fine with only `Alt+A` on `accesskey="a"`.

Comment: and 5 years later this comes in Handy again, thanks @BalusC